# How would I remove borders from all Floating windows in XMonad

Tags: haskell, xmonad

There are several similar questions but none quite solve it for me, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498979/remove-border-from-fullscreen-floating-windows-only-xmonad-configuration) question explains how to remove borders from fullscreen floating windows.

Using [XMonad.Layout.NoBorders](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Layout-NoBorders.html) you can do lots of cool stuff like remove borders from certain windows or if it is the only window or only fullscreen floating windows.

I couldn't find anything for all floating windows, however if someone could just point me to some tool that I could use to check if a window is floating or not, I am sure I could try hack up a solution.

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll be using the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/src/XMonad-Layout-NoBorders.html) of XMonad.Layout.NoBorders as a reference, since I can't find anything more fitting that already exists. We want to see how it implements "remove borders on fullscreen floating windows", to see if it can be easily relaxed to "remove borders on floating windows" (without the fullscreen constraint).

According to the answer on the question you linked:

```
layoutHook = lessBorders OnlyFloat $ avoidStruts $ myLayout
```

`OnlyFloat` seems to be the specifier for "remove borders on fullscreen floating windows", so let's check the definition of that:

```
data Ambiguity = Combine With Ambiguity Ambiguity
               | OnlyFloat
               | Never
               | EmptyScreen
               | OtherIndicated
               | Screen
    deriving (Read, Show)
```

Not too helpful on its own. We should look elsewhere to see how the code treats these values.

---

It's a pretty safe bet that the first function to check is `lessBorders`:

```
lessBorders :: (SetsAmbiguous p, Read p, Show p, LayoutClass l a) =>
        p -> l a -> ModifiedLayout (ConfigurableBorder p) l a
lessBorders amb = ModifiedLayout (ConfigurableBorder amb [])
```

From the type signature of `lessBorders`, we can see that:

```
OnlyFloat :: (SetsAmbiguous p, Read p, Show p) => p
```

This is a good sign, as it means `lessBorders` doesn't explicitly expect an `Ambiguity`: we can extend the functionality here by implementing our own `SetsAmbiguous` and passing it to the existing `lessBorders`. Let's now look at `SetsAmbiguous`, and `Ambiguity`'s implementation of it:

```
class SetsAmbiguous p where
    hiddens :: p -> WindowSet -> Maybe (W.Stack Window) -> [(Window, Rectangle)] -> [Window]

instance SetsAmbiguous Ambiguity where
    hiddens amb wset mst wrs
      | Combine Union a b <- amb = on union next a b
      | Combine Difference a b <- amb = on (\\) next a b
      | Combine Intersection a b <- amb = on intersect next a b
      | otherwise = tiled ms ++ floating
      where next p = hiddens p wset mst wrs
            nonzerorect (Rectangle _ _ 0 0) = False
            nonzerorect _ = True
            screens =
              [ scr | scr <- W.screens wset,
                      case amb of
                            Never -> True
                            _ -> not $ null $ integrate scr,
                      nonzerorect . screenRect $ W.screenDetail scr]
            floating = [ w |
                        (w, W.RationalRect px py wx wy) <- M.toList . W.floating $ wset,
                        px <= 0, py <= 0,
                        wx + px >= 1, wy + py >= 1]
            ms = filter (`elem` W.integrate' mst) $ map fst wrs
            tiled [w]
              | Screen <- amb = [w]
              | OnlyFloat <- amb = []
              | OtherIndicated <- amb
              , let nonF = map integrate $ W.current wset : W.visible wset
              , length (concat nonF) > length wrs
              , singleton $ filter (1==) $ map length nonF = [w]
              | singleton screens = [w]
            tiled _ = []
            integrate y = W.integrate' . W.stack $ W.workspace y
```

`hiddens` is the only method here that we need to implement. Its arguments are our `SetsAmbiguous` value, a `WindowSet`, and some other things, and it returns a list of windows that should not show borders. There's a lot of logic for the combining operations and other `Ambiguity` values, but those don't matter to us right now. What we care about is this snippet:

```
            floating = [ w |
                        (w, W.RationalRect px py wx wy) <- M.toList . W.floating $ wset,
                        px <= 0, py <= 0,
                        wx + px >= 1, wy + py >= 1]
```

This is very promising. It defines a set of floating windows by extracting all windows from the `floating` section of the `WindowSet`, converting it to a list (initially it's a `Data.Map`), and filtering out all the windows that don't cover the entire screen. All we need to do is remove the filter.

---

After making that change, and removing all unnecessary code pertaining to tiled windows and set operations (which is most of the implementation), we end up with simply:

```
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import qualified Data.Map as M

data AllFloats = AllFloats deriving (Read, Show)

instance SetsAmbiguous AllFloats where
    hiddens _ wset _ _ = M.keys $ W.floating wset
```

We can then say:

```
layoutHook = lessBorders AllFloats $ myLayout...
```

Comment: Wow thanks for your in depth answer. I am someone who barely knows Haskell, only the real basics and you explained it so well I could understand. This is honestly one of the best answers I have ever seen on a question. Cheers.

Comment: One question I do have. I have noticed that in haskell when you import stuff, for one reason or another sometimes you have to do something like `import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W`. I assume that is what you have done here for the letter M. Just wondering what import is M?

Comment: Because you use the word keys and its an M I assume it is `Data.Map`?

Comment: I can't quite get it to work. I get a Type error as follows "Couldn't match expected type [(Window, Rectangle)] -> [Window] with actual type [Window] In the expression: M.keys $ W.floating wset

Comment: @Dylan Yeah, since I modified this code from XMonad.Layout.NoBorders I used the same imports that uses. I edited my answer and added the imports for clarity. You don't really need to [qualify imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274864/what-does-qualified-mean-in-import-qualified-data-list-statement), but it's a good idea because it makes it obvious where the functions you're calling come from. This is especially important if multiple libraries you're importing define functions with the same names.

Comment: @Dylan Are you sure your `hiddens` has the correct number of arguments? So `hiddens _ wset _ _ = ...` rather than `hiddens _ wset _ = ...`?

Comment: I managed to get it work. I had to write "hiddens _ wset _ _ _ =" instead of "hiddens _ wset _ _".

Comment: Not related to this question at all, but since you seem to know a lot. Is there any better way to define window sizes in XMonad with a type better than RationalRect? Maybe something that defines the size by distance from the edge of the screen in pixels?

Comment: @Dylan Oh that's strange, it shouldn't take that many arguments. I mean if it works it works, but I must be missing something in that case ... I think most stuff only takes `RationalRect`, but with some math you can write a function that does the conversion to `RationalRect`, and pass your pixel coordinates and the total screen size into that.